# Transmutation with cosmic radiation possible?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, cosmic-rays, data

Can cosmic radiation (alpha radiation) transmute the material of a space craft, particular carbon, titanium and aluminum?

Where can i find transmutation tables or formulas to calculate the possibility of a transmutation and the outcome?

Answer (score 6):

Happens all the time. Low background neutrino detectors have to contend with the products: short lived, light isotopes that are created in after cosmic rays knock some neutrons loose from other material (neutron spallation).

See (to chose an example I'm an author on) [DOI 10.1103/PhysRevC.81.025807](http://prc.aps.org/abstract/PRC/v81/i2/e025807) (also at [arXiv:0907.0066](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0907.0066)). You can also find simlar papers for other low background detectors.

There is not, however, anything like a table for human consumption. The size of the data set is prohibitively large. It is available in a form for computer consumption as [Evaluated Nuclear Data Files](http://www-nds.iaea.org/exfor/endf.htm) plus the cosmic ray spectrum (which I don't have a link for off hand). If you are interested in what happens after the cosmic ray showers you'll need a full Monte Carlo: [CRY](http://nuclear.llnl.gov/simulation/main.html) or something equivalent.

---

Mind you, when I say "happens all the time" I am talking about a small number of atoms per second in any reasonable volume of matter, which means that you basically can't notice it without building a sizable low background detector because of the pure *number* or atoms in any given macroscopic sample of mass.

Remember class, [Avogodro's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) is very, *very* big indeed.